# Read in Binary File - Little Endian

Tags: python

I have created a binary file as shown below.
How would I read the contents of this file into a variable?

```
import struct 

with open("test-09.bin", "wb") as fp:
    fp.write(struct.pack("<4d", 3.14159, 42.0, 123.456, 987.654))

with open("test-09.bin", "rb") as fp:
    fp.read(struct.unpack("<4d", ????))
```

Comment: Think about which function is executed first; `fp.read` or `struct.unpack`. If you're unsure, you should avoid calling two functions in the same line for now and write the function calls as two separate statements in two lines in the order you intend.

Answer (score 3):

You have the logic backwards - read the file contents as an argument to `unpack`, which will return the unpacked data - like this:

```
with open("test-09.bin", "rb") as fp:
    nums = struct.unpack("<4d", fp.read())
```

which sets `nums` to:

```
(3.14159, 42.0, 123.456, 987.654)
```

**Update**: As @tdelaney pointed out, it's probably best to not assume the size of the read, so a bit more comprehensive approach might be:

```
format = "<4d"
size = struct.calcsize(format)
with open("test-09.bin", "rb") as fp:
    data = fp.read(size)
if len(data) == size:
    nums = struct.unpack("<4d", data)
else:
    print("short file read")
```

Comment: This is a good answer but I think you should read just the size of the structure, in this case `fp.read(32)` or using `struct.calcsize` to figure it out.